# Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync returns error 9020 An internal error has occured

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am using a tutorial that gets the email email properties using Outlook Add-in and now I am trying to get the email body. All the research I am getting is using mostly this statement to get it.

```
function getEmailBody() {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function callback(asyncResult) {
       return asyncResult.value;
});
```

But when I run it, it returns empty and when I put a debugger on it, the asyncResult has these values:

```
value: null
status: failed
error: OSF.DDA.Error
  name: GenericResponseError
  message: An internal error has occurred.
  code: 9020
```

Does anyone knows what is causing this error? I am using outlook.office.com in Google Chrome to access the emails.

Comment: Is this issue occurring in the Window opened using Office.context.mailbox.displayMessageForm() API ?

Comment: No, it is not, I am calling the code I mentioned above using the outlook add-in JavaScript. One weird thing though is returning actual value when run against an Outlook app, but not working when run from a browser.

Comment: Is there any test account from where this issue can be repro-ed ?

Comment: I'm just running into the same issue...

To add some details:
1) I'm having a Office 365 business account 
2) It works in Outlook for Windows 
3) it does not work on Web for Chrome neither in IE. 
4) It does not work for our add-in nor for others I've tested that use the email body
5) it works for others in my team, so it seems to be mailbox specific

Comment: @DarkLegend is it possible for us to reproduce this on a test account for which this issue happens?